# passive motion sensor

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, motion, sleep, movement

I would like to get a microcontroller out of sleep when the board starts moving (or vibrating). If possible it should just be a passive switch (I only need a positive edge from a battery to get the board started, and I don't care about other behaviour).
I was first thinking of a TILT switch, but I think it is a bit too restricted (i.e. 15DEG in a predefined direction...).
Think of a bicycle light that should start shining when a bicycle starts moving. However, this is for a big machine.
Preferably surface mount. 
Is there a proper name for those sensors (I keep on hitting on PIR sensors)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want a PIR sensor - those detect movement in infrared, and the signal requires conditioning for proper detection. Along the lines of a tilt/vibration sensor, I came across this, which is SMT, simple, and small, https://signalquest.com/product/components/sq-sen-200/ (http://www.glynstore.com/signalquest-sq-sen-390-tilt-sensor/).

Comment: DigitalNinja, this is indeed what I am looking for, if you put your comment as an answer I will check it. Not digikey sourceable, but that is MY problem :)

Comment: I think PIR sensors would not help because it would detect humans only as far as I know...however I may be wrong so first if you would like...do some experiments with Pir sensor whether it would detect ur board or not.

Comment: no no no, no PIR sensors, this is really very different from what I look for. DigitalNinja sent a great link! That's my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, PIR sensors work well for detecting movement in infrared (mainly used for human occupancy detection) and require signal conditioning.

I think a tilt/vibration sensor would work well for your application and this one happens to be small, surface mount, and acts like a simple open/close switch. Even one of the applications listed is for "motion trigger wake-up". They come in a few different part numbers which you can look over (there's a "mini" version which is even smaller!). They are kind of expensive when it comes to a board component, and a little hard to find, but you will probably get a price break if you are making a bunch of these boards. If not then it's a one time cost for something that seems to do exactly what you want. I didn't try very hard to find any other stores/distributors that carry it. Maybe you can find some more.

Manufacturer link: https://signalquest.com/product/components/sq-sen-200/

Store: http://www.glynstore.com/signalquest-sq-sen-200-omnidirectional-tilt-vibration-sensor/

Variations:

http://www.glynstore.com/signalquest-sq-min-200-omnidirectional-tilt-vibration-sensor/
http://www.glynstore.com/signalquest-sq-sen-390-tilt-sensor/
http://www.glynstore.com/signalquest-sq-sen-815-tilt-sensor/